# Batch "download as" in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I have a bunch of .doc files in my Google Drive that I would like to download as HTML. (i.e. open file, download as > WebPage html )

Does anyone know how I can do the conversion for all the files without having to "download as" each file manually?